# 503 error when trying to access VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, connection-timeout, http-status-code-503

We've been using VSTS for the last couple of months with no issues at all, until this morning during the day it suddenly became very slow and started giving us 503 error when trying to access it.

No particular actions were being done on it, just updating stories with their updates.

Anyone else had this issue and maybe could suggest what can be done to fix it/access VSTS again? We have everything in VSTS and this is potentially very bad for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually happens when servicing is happening. It's not just you let's say that. With enough luck it will be resolved by the team behind VSTS and you'll be able to use your stuff again.

Refer to https://status.dev.azure.com/ for updates from the team (They've even updated it now for todays issue!)

Comment: Thank you - didn't know about this link.